# pre commit hook files skipped

Tags: terraform, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/terraform-docs/terraform-docs
    rev: "v0.16.0"
    hooks:
      - id: terraform-docs-go
        args: ["markdown", "table", "--output-file", "README.md", "./"]
  - repo: https://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform
    rev: "v1.74.1"
    hooks:
      - id: terraform_fmt
```

files are being skipped, and only when i run this manually

pre-commit run --all-files

Will the hook run, so when i run git add . && git commit -m 'whatever' it doesnt check... whats the point of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pre-commit will only run on files changed in the commit.  there's no reason to re-lint a file that already passes checks over and over wasting time

if you're not changing terraform files in a commit then your terraform linters will not run

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: thanks sorry about my rant i appreciate your work

Comment: Hah! I love this humble reply. Disclaimer: I wrote the thing. 

Thanks for your hard work and for answering the question in a humble way.